# How do I create new instance of Generic Type Class

Tags: c#, algorithm, generics, parse-platform, abstract-class

Questions:

1. How do I create, set, and return and instantiated object of type "T"?
2. How would I access the subclass type (Tag : DataBASE) in a static function?

I'm trying to create a generic "GetAsClass" function which would return an initialized instance of the subclass. I can't figure out how to create a new instance of the class I want to return and return the subclass type.

Say I have two classes:

1. Tag
2. User

I want to create a single function in the base class which will get whatever type it is. On another note, I'd like to make it static as well (but then I don't have access to "this" and I'm not sure how to get the subclass type.

```
    private async Task<T> GetAsClass<T>(string objectId) {

        Type classType = this.GetType();
        string className = classType.Name; 

        // This needs to be of type "T" (Tag myTag = new Tag();) How would I accomplish something like this?
        object toReturnObject = new object();
        ParseObject myParseObject = ParseObject.GetAsParseObject(objectId);

        foreach (PropertyInfo field in classType.GetRuntimeProperties()) {
            if (field.CanRead) {
                string propertyName = StringHelper.ToLowerCamelCase(field.Name);
                if (field.PropertyType == typeof(string)) {
                    string propertyValue = myParseObject.Get<string>(propertyName);
                    field.SetValue(toReturnObject , propertyValue);
                }
                if (field.PropertyType == typeof(int)) {
                    int propertyValue = myParseObject.Get<int>(propertyName);
                    field.SetValue(toReturnObject, propertyValue);
                }
            }
        }

        return toReturnObject;
    }
```

[image: Code so far]
Higher Resolution: http://snag.gy/FbCfu.jpg

Comment: Does my code logic make sense? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: You should post your code as text, not as an image... The markup (called `markdown`) has the capability to take a section of your question as code, and perform syntax highlighting, etc.

Comment: Seems harder to read than a screenshot in my opinion, but okay sure, if that will get people to help me. Now how about some help with my question instead of constructive criticism regarding semantics.

Comment: Just a comment: don't put comments after the code, put the comments before the code. Also, I see too many comments in there. Are you sure you can't make your code more readable by making more functions?

Comment: Removed comments and pointed out questions better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find this page on [generic type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to be helpful.
Basically, you would change the signature of your class/method to be:

```
private async Task<T> GetAsClass<T>(string objectId)
    where T: new()
{
    ...
}
```

And it will accept types of T only if it provides a default constructor with no arguments. Once that condition is guaranteed, then your class can invoke `new T()`

Comment: Awesome! That sounds exactly like what I was looking for. I'll give it a shot once I finish up some other code.